# How can I bind a gridview to datasource with dynamic WHERE clause?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview, datasource

I am using Visual Basic for ASP. NET

I know how to populate a gridview with data using only code behind, like this

```
Dim ds as new datasourse
Dim da as new dataadaptor
Dim con as new SqlConnection
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand
... 
Cmd = "select ticketID, problem_text from problems where support_engineer = " & Session("Logged_in_user_id")
... 
Gridview1.Datasource = ds
Gridview1.Datasources. DataBind
```

And that works fines,  but my question is: how can i drag and drop a gridview control, and using only the wizard to populate the gridview in design time, how can i define the SELECT statement to only select rows that are related to the logged in user id? See the sql statement above, it uses a session variable that i create in Page_Load event, but how can i use the same logic in design mode? (i don't want to modify the datasource control in code behind)

I looked in youtube and google, and this sites,  but all results are simply showing me how to populate the gridview with all rows or with a static condition, not a dynamic one like the one i demonestrated.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the proper way of binding the gridview to a dynamic session variable, without involving code behind:. Simply use the property `<SessionParameter>` inside the `<SelectParameter>`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT ticketID, problem_text FROM problems 
               WHERE (support_engineer = @eng_id) 

<SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter 
              Name="eng_id" 
              SessionField="LoggedInUser" 
              Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try replacing the form tag in the aspx file

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ticketID, problem_text FROM Tabs WHERE (support_engineer = @Param1)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Param1" SessionField="Logged_in_user_id" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but here is what I got: Attribute 'SessionField' is not a valid attribute of element 'Parameter'